# convert marks into percentage

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

how to convert marks obtained by a student into x% 
i.e. there are two exams. calculate certain %marks from both exams (say x% and Y%) so that the total will be 100%

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. We have no way to know if your exams are stored vertically, horizontally, what the other columns are, etc.

Comment: what have you tried so far?? show your efforts and then write your query that causing error.

Comment: Why is SQL tagged in this?  Are you having trouble with reading the data from a database?  Or are you trying to calculate the value in a SQL statement?

Comment: yes, i have marks for different subjects obtained by a student in exam 1 and exam 2 in the database. i need to read each mark, calculate x% of this marks from exam 1 and exam 2 and add these two so that the result is the marks out of 100.

Comment: But which part of the task are you having trouble with?  Also, please show us an example of what you mean.

Comment: there are two tests say A and B. A is of 50 marks and B is of 100 marks. i need to calculate 10% of A and 90% of B, so that i get the total out of 100

Comment: do i first need to convert marks out of 50 to 100 before calculating 10%from A?

Comment: Is this part of the the same homework question from earlier - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933036/exam-result-calculation-of-school-in-vb-net

Comment: @MattWilko It doesn't really matter if it's homework or not.  Either it's a valid question or it isn't.

Comment: @SteveDog - my point was about whether it should have a homework tag or not

Comment: @MattWilko There's been a debate in the meta site regarding deleting that tag outright as many people think it's useless and creates unnecessary tension taking the focus off the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited info that you have provided, I think you might be asking for the following:

```
create table student
(
    id int,
    s_name varchar(10)
)
insert into student values (1, 'Jim')
insert into student values (2, 'Bob')
insert into student values (3, 'Jane')

create table exams
(
    id int,
    e_name varchar(10)
)
insert into exams values (1, 'Test 1')
insert into exams values (2, 'Test 2')
insert into exams values (3, 'Test 3')
insert into exams values (4, 'Test 4')

create table exam_student
(
    e_id int,
    s_id int,
    dt datetime,
    score decimal(5,2)
)
insert into exam_student values(1, 1, '2012-08-01', 65.0)
insert into exam_student values(1, 2, '2012-08-01', 85.0)
insert into exam_student values(2, 1, '2012-08-02', 75.0)
insert into exam_student values(2, 2, '2012-08-02', 42.0)


select avg(es.score) as ScorePct, s_id, s.s_name
from exam_student es
inner join exams e
    on es.e_id = e.id
inner join student s
    on es.s_id = s.id
group by s_id, s_name
```

Results:

[image]

If you provide more details on exactly what you are looking for that would be helpful in answering your question.